# Flutter : need update auth service class

Tags: flutter, dart

I create Auth Class for firebase Auth version 0.11.1+10, now after update the packege firebase auth to last version some code is error.

```
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  String email, String password, String name) async {
final currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email,
  password: password,
);


//updat username is error code ***************************
var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
userUpdateInfo.displayname = name;
await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
await currentUser.reload();
return currentUser.uid;
```

}

[See Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VI0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

`UserUpdateInfo`  is now deprecated but you can use this instead

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile();
```

And you pass the info you want to update to `updateProfile()`